# libpq code to create, list and delete databases (C++/VC++, PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, visual-c++

I am new to the PostgreSQL database. What my visual c++ application needs to do is to create multiple tables and add/retrieve data from them.

Each session of my application should create a new and distinct database. I can use the current date and time for a unique database name.

There should also be an option to delete all the databases.

I have worked out how to connect to a database, create tables, and add data to tables. I am not sure how to make a new database for each run or how to retrieve number and name of databases if user want to clear all databases.

Please help.

Comment: Please be more specific. PostgreSQL version? How are you connecting to PostgreSQL - via ODBC, ADO, native libpq, libpqtypes/libpqxx, Npgsql, NHibernate, what?

Comment: would use latest version like 9.1.4.1. And I will be connecting using libpq.

Comment: if you know how to issue CREATE TABLE with libpq, you can do CREATE DATABASE based on almost the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [libpq examples in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-example.html). The example program shows you how to list databases, and in general how to execute commands against the database. The example code there is trivial to adapt to creating and dropping databases.

Creating a database is a simple [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-createdb.html) SQL statement, same as any other libpq operation. You must connect to a temporary database (usually `template1`) to issue the `CREATE DATABASE`, then disconnect and make a new connection to the database you just created.

Rather than creating new databases, consider creating new [schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createschema.html) instead. Much less hassle, since all you need to do is change the [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) or prefix your table references, you don't have to disconnect and reconnect to change schemas. See [the documentation on schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html).

I question the wisdom of your design, though. It is rarely a good idea for applications to be creating and dropping databases (or tables, except temporary tables) as a normal part of their operation. Maybe if you elaborated on *why* you want to do this, we can come up with solutions that may be easier and/or perform better than your current approach.

Comment: each execution of my application needs few (7-8) tables. And at each execution, a fresh set of tables should be created. Old tables should persist till user wants. Now, for creating a different set of tables at each execution, I think making a different database with time stamp can help me.
And, giving user option of removing old tables, I can easily remove all databases which will in-turn remove all tables. before creating new one for the current session.

Comment: also, the link you gave me, give examples of creating tables. Did not find anything about creating database. Maybe I am new so don't know the exact command/syntax.

Comment: @Garfield The second link is to the `CREATE DATABASE` command syntax.  It's an ordinary SQL command like any other, so you can use it in a `PQexec` call. You must connect to a database like `template1` to issue the `CREATE DATABASE` then *disconnect* and make a new connection to your new database to work with it.

Comment: @Garfield As for your design: If the only need to exist for a single application session, use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` so they're auto dropped on disconnect. You might also find PostgreSQL 9.1's `UNLOGGED` table feature interesting if the tables contain data that you don't mind losing if something goes wrong. In general creating tables and databases on the fly suggests you might not be using the right tool for the job, though.

Comment: Rather than creating new databases, I suggest you create [schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createschema.html) instead, so you can keep using the same database. Much less hassle. See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html)

Comment: @Garfield: You're just reiterating what you're trying to do, not explaining what you want to accomplish.. The sane approach would be to store everything in a single database. Execution metadata, such as that time stamp you mention above, should be _rows_ in a table called "executions", _not_ new DBs..

Comment: @eevar Much as I suspect it's a bad idea, there *are* some cases where Garfield's approach may be reasonable - mainly if the tables are large. Consider it an extreme case of table partitioning. It's hard to know given the lack of available information.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Sure. But given that he doesn't seem to understand why you're questioning his design and provide a valid rationale for the approach, I think it's fair to assume he is new to RDBMSs and going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @eevar Absolutely. I'm just being pedantic ;-)