# libpq very slow for large (20 million record) database

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-c++

I am new to SQL/RDBMS.

I have an application which adds rows with 10 columns in PostgreSQL server using the libpq library. Right now, my server is running on same machine as my visual c++ application.

I have added around 15-20 million records. The simple query of getting total count is taking 4-5 minutes using `select count(*) from <tableName>;`.

I have indexed my table with the time I am entering the data (timecode). Most of the time I need count with different `WHERE` / `AND` clauses added.

Is there any way to make things fast? I need to make it as fast as possible because once the server moves to network, things will become much slower.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Postgres are you on?

Comment: @garfield Every time you [post a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650018/libpq-code-to-create-list-and-delete-databases-c-vc-postgresql), someone asks you for your PostgreSQL version. Isn't that a hint that you should *put it in when you ask the question*?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your hardware. 5 Minutes for a `count(*)` is far too long.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Something wrong with the hardware, concurrent queries running, or massive table bloat, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think network latency will be a large factor in how long your query takes. All the processing is being done on the PostgreSQL server.

The PostgreSQL MVCC design means each row in the table - not just the index(es) - must be walked to calculate the count(*) which is an expensive operation. In your case there are a lot of rows involved.

There is a good wiki page on this topic here http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting with suggestions.

Two suggestions from this link, one is to use an index column:

```
select count(index-col) from ...;
```

... though this only works under some circumstances.

If you have more than one index see which one has the least cost by using:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(index-col) from ...;
```

If you can live with an approximate value, another is to use a Postgres specific function for an approximate value like:

```
select reltuples from pg_class where relname='mytable';
```

How good this approximation is depends on how often autovacuum is set to run and many other factors; see the comments.

Comment: But this can help me in fetching count of total table. In table entries, I have a column which is sequentially increasing long integer. Total count will be equal to value at that column of last row. This much optimization can be done. But when a "where" and "and" is added in my query, this is where things get worse.
Moreover, if I provide column name in my "count(...)", how will it make any difference as again postgre have to go through all the columns to get me the count.

Comment: If your columns are indexed PG will only have to count index entries - not the full table rows. Also, putting a where clause will restrict the rows and should speed things up. Try it out. And you can try different indexes + EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see what effect they have.

Comment: @Garfield When you say "sequentially increasing long integer" do you mean a `SEQUENCE` or `SERIAL` / `BIGSERIAL` ? Because they can have gaps or holes. The maximum ID is not necessarily equal to the number of rows even if you have never deleted a row. Every time you do an `INSERT` then roll back the transaction, you throw generated IDs away, leaving a hole. Holes can happen in other ways too. `max(id)` is **not** the same thing as `count(id)` for a `serial`.

Comment: @pd420 That's actually not the case. Even if doing an index scan PostgreSQL must still hit the table heap to examine visibility data, as explained by the slow counting wiki article you linked to. This has improved a lot with the new "index only scans" feature in 9.2, but for prior versions visibility must still be checked. The visibility map in (IIRC) 8.4 and above can allow some shortcuts to be taken if it's up to date, but has limitations.

Comment: @CraigRinger: How would statistics targets be relevant for `reltuples`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I *thought* `ANALYZE` approximated the row count through heap sampling controlled by the stats targets. Am I completely mistaken in that?

Comment: @CraigRinger: I was not entirely sure myself and hoping to get more information from you. :) So I studied the manual some more and it's rather complex. `reltuples` is set by various operations. Besides `ANALYZE`, also by `VACUUM`, `VACUUM FULL`, `CLUSER`, `CREATE INDEX` .. and others - Postgres uses every opportunity. With big tables, `ANALYZE` only scans a random sample of pages and saves an estimate. The highest `statistics_target` between all columns is used to determine the number of pages in the random sample. This way it can have a (small) effect on the accuracy of `reltuples`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `pg_relation_size('tablename')` and divide it by the seconds spent in

```
select count(*) from tablename
```

That will give the throughput of your disk(s) when doing a full scan of this table. If it's too low, you want to focus on improving that in the first place.
Having a good I/O subsystem and well performing operating system disk cache is crucial for databases.

The default postgres configuration is meant to not consume too much resources to play nice with other applications. Depending on your hardware and the overall utilization of the machine, you may want to adjust several performance parameters way up, like **shared_buffers**, **effective_cache_size** or **work_mem**. See the docs for your specific version and the wiki's [performance optimization](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) page.

Also note that the speed of `select count(*)`-style queries have nothing to do with `libpq` or the network, since only one resulting row is retrieved. It happens entirely server-side.

Comment: It can also be slowed by table bloat, so watch out for that. Make sure autovacuum is running often if you do lots of `update`s and `delete`s.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what your data is, but normally the why to handle tables with a very large amount of data is to partition the table. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html

This will not speed up your `select count(*) from <tableName>;` query, and might even slow it down, but if you are normally only interested in a portion of the data in the table this can be helpful.