# Retrieve a list of the databases from postgres server via libpq

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I've tried to find a way to ask the postgres server for the current list of databases (and later list and describe the tables) from a C program using the libpq library. Currently I'm doing a (simplified) `popen("psql --command '\\l'")` but this is not really how I would like to solve the problem ... Is there any way of asking the postgres server for the information I need via a libpq function?

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650018/libpq-code-to-create-list-and-delete-databases-c-vc-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a metadata query like

```
SELECT ... FROM pg_database;

The columns you select will depend on the information you need.
```